# TypeError: dialog.showOpenDialogSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

Использую electron-vue. Хочу открыть диалог выбора файла:

```
const { dialog } = this.$electron
dialog.showOpenDialogSync({})
```

Получаю ошибку: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'showOpenDialogSync' of undefined`. Сам `this.$electron` существует.

Comment: попробуйте сделать, как в документации написано, через `require`

Comment: @Дмытрык пробовал. Тоже самое.